# Dart and JSON: Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I'm attempting to access a JSON response from a server so I can output the contents on the screen, but I keep getting the error message: Unhandled Exception: type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast. I'm fairly new to Dart and Json as a whole so I'm not sure where to go to fix this.
Here's the code I have written:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import './user_credentials_struct.dart';

class Credentials with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Accounts> _items = [];

  List<Accounts> get items {
    return [..._items];
  }

  Future<void> fetchAccounts() async {
    final selectAccountUrl =
        Uri.parse('https://cs.csub.edu/~tesscuro/database/selectAccounts.php');
    try {
      final response = await http.get(selectAccountUrl);
      final receivedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      final List<Accounts> loadedData = [];
      receivedData.forEach((accountID, data) {
        loadedData.add(
          Accounts(
            id: accountID,
            siteUrl: data['url'],
            password: data['password'],
            userName: data['username'],
          ),
        );
      });
      _items = loadedData;
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
}
```

And this is a sample of the JSON response I get:

```
[{"cID":1,"url":"www.google.com","username":"test","password":"password"},{"cID":1,"url":"www.youtube.com","username":"test1","password":"password1"}]
```

I've changed the parameter types from String to ints, and rewritten code with different examples found. I've also changed the Map types to try and make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically your response is returning a `List` instead of a `Map` in other words you can write `json.decode(response.body) as List<dynamic>`. My suggestion is that you can use https://app.quicktype.io/ for creating your models by utilizing the existing JSON. In your case the model looks like this

```
class Accounts {
  Accounts({
    required this.cId,
    required this.url,
    required this.username,
    required this.password,
  });

  int cId;
  String url;
  String username;
  String password;

  factory Accounts.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Accounts(
        cId: json["cID"],
        url: json["url"],
        username: json["username"],
        password: json["password"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "cID": cId,
        "url": url,
        "username": username,
        "password": password,
      };
}
```

Now inside of your `fetchAccounts` function, your implementation will look like this

```
Future<void> fetchAccounts() async {
    final selectAccountUrl = Uri.parse('https://cs.csub.edu/~tesscuro/database/selectAccounts.php');
    try {
      final response = await http.get(selectAccountUrl);
      final receivedData = json.decode(response.body);
      print(receivedData);
      final listOfData = List<Accounts>.from(receivedData.map((x) => Accounts.fromJson(x)));
      _items = listOfData;
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

Basically, it takes the response data and converts your data into list of accounts. I hope this solves your confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Read the error

> type `'List<dynamic>'` is not a subtype of type `'Map<String, dynamic>'`
> in type cast

json response is `List` you should use

```
 final receivedData = json.decode(response.body) as List<dynamic>;
```

Then you can convert it to `Accounts` object like this:

```
 final loadedData = receivedData
      .map((json) => Accounts(
          id: json['id'],
          siteUrl: json['url'],
          password: json['password'],
          userName: json['username']))
      .toList();
```

The better approach is to have `fromJson` , `toJson` converters as part of `Account` class then you can simply write:

```
final loadedData = receivedData
     .map((e) => Account.fromJson( e as Map<String,dynamic>))
     .toList();
```